# Laravel Many To Many Get Fields From Both Tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, many-to-many, relationship

I have 3 tables:

1. Genre model: id, name, slug, etc.
2. GenreStation model: id, genre_id, station_id.
3. Station model: id, name, slug, logo, etc.

I'm trying to get data by genre slug from station table with offset and limit parameters. But also I want to fetch genre name using this query:

```
Genre::slug($genreSlug)
        ->first()
        ->stations()
        ->skip($offset)
        ->take($limit)
        ->get([
            'genres.name as genre_name',
            'stations.id',
            'stations.name',
            'stations.slug',
            'stations.stream_url',
            'stations.logo',
            'stations.media_type',
            'stations.bit_rate',
            'stations.listeners',
            'stations.status',
        ]);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> "Illuminate\Database\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'genres.name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `genres`.`name` as `genre_name`, `stations`.`id`, `stations`.`name`, `stations`.`slug`, `stations`.`stream_url`, `stations`.`logo`, `stations`.`media_type`, `stations`.`bit_rate`, `stations`.`listeners`, `stations`.`status`, `genre_station`.`genre_id` as `pivot_genre_id`, `genre_station`.`station_id` as `pivot_station_id`, `genre_station`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `genre_station`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `stations` inner join `genre_station` on `stations`.`id` = `genre_station`.`station_id` where `genre_station`.`genre_id` = 1 limit 15 offset 0)","file":"/home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php","line":625

Without `genre.name` field everything works fine. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the SQL query you can already see what is going wrong. Probably the first query will get you the Genre, but afterwards a new query is made for the stations and they are based on the `genre_station` table. You don't have any information from the `genres` table, so you should add this.

You can do this by adding a join to the query..
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins

Or first save the Genre in a separate variable and get the stations after..

```
$genre = Genre::slug($genreSlug)->first();
$stations = $genre->stations()
    ->skip($offset)
    ->take($limit)
    ->get([
        'stations.id',
        'stations.name',
        'stations.slug',
        'stations.stream_url',
        'stations.logo',
        'stations.media_type',
        'stations.bit_rate',
        'stations.listeners',
        'stations.status',
    ]);
```

Comment: It's work for me, but I'm trying to solve this using 1 query, to escape merging genre and station objects.

Comment: I think your solution already uses 2 queries under water, but to get the desired result you could also add a join like `->join('genres', 'genre_station.genre_id', '=', 'genres.id')`, which should be after `->stations()`

Comment: I solved the problem using join after `->stations()`. I'm not sure about excellence of this variant, but it's working. Thank you for help!